# Представление характеристик в Django admin

Tags: python, json, django, django-admin

Подскажите как сделать представление характеристик в админке чтобы получилось так https://ibb.co/qDTSjYx

models.py

```
class Category(MPTTModel):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Категории'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250,verbose_name='Имя категории')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):

        try:

            ancestors = self.get_ancestors(include_self=True)
            ancestors = [i.name for i in ancestors]
        except:
            ancestors = [self.name]

        return ' > '.join(ancestors[:len(ancestors) + 1])

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('category_detail',kwargs={'slug': self.slug})




    def get_fields_for_filter_in_template(self):
        return ProductFeatures.objects.filter(
            category=self,
            use_in_filter=True
        ).prefetch_related('category').value('feature_key','feature_measure','feature_name','filter_type')
    @property
    def get_products(self):
        return Product.objects.filter(category__name=self.name)


class Product(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Продукт'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Продукты'
        order_with_respect_to='slug'

    category =  TreeForeignKey(Category, blank=True, null=True, related_name='category', verbose_name="Выберите категорию",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250,verbose_name='Наименоватние продукта')
    slug=models.SlugField(unique=True)
    image1 = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Главное изображение')
    image2 = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True, verbose_name='Изображение 2')
    image3 = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True, verbose_name='Изображение 3')
    image4 = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True, verbose_name='Изображение 4')
    image5 = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True, verbose_name='Изображение 5')
    characteristics = JSONField(blank=True,null=True)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Описание товара',null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2,verbose_name='Цена')



    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


    def get_model_name(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__.lower()

    def get_characteristics(self):
        res={}
        characteristics={
            f.feature_key: {'feature_name':f.feature_name,'postfix':f.postfix_for_value}
            for f in ProductFeatures.objects.filter(
                feature_key__in=self.characteristics.keys()
            ).prefetch_related('category')
        }
        for feature_key,feature_value in self.characteristics.items():
            postfix = characteristics[feature_key].get('postfix')
            if postfix:
                res[characteristics[feature_key]['feature_name']] = feature_value + ' ' + postfix
            else:
                res[characteristics[feature_key]['feature_name']] = feature_value
        return res

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product_detail',kwargs={'slug':self.slug})
    
    def get_feature_value_by_key(self,key):
        return self.characteristics.get(key)

class ProductFeatureValidators(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,verbose_name='Категория',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    feature= models.ForeignKey(ProductFeatures, verbose_name='Характеристика',null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    feature_value= models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True,null=True,blank=True,verbose_name='Значение хар-ки')

    def __str__(self):
        if not self.feature:
            return f'Валидатор категории "{self.category.name}"- Хар-ка не выбрана'
        return f'Валидатор категории"{self.category.name} | '\
                f'Характеристика - "{self.feature.feature_name}"|'\
                f'Значение - "{self.feature_value}"'


class ProductFeatures(models.Model):
     
    RADIO='radio'
    CHECKBOX='checkbox'
    FILTER_TYPE_CHOICES=(
        (RADIO,'Радиокнопка'),
        (CHECKBOX,'Чекбокс')
    )
    feature_key = models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name='Ключ характеристики')
    feature_name= models.CharField(max_length=255,verbose_name='Наименование характеристики')
    category= models.ForeignKey(Category,verbose_name='Категория',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    postfix_for_value= models.CharField(
        max_length=25,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name='Постфикс для значения',
        help_text=f'Для хар-к можно добавить постфикс'
    )
    use_in_filter=models.CharField(max_length=50,
        default=False,
        verbose_name='Использовать в фильтрации товаров на странице'
    )
    filter_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        verbose_name='Тип фильтра',
        default=CHECKBOX,
        choices=FILTER_TYPE_CHOICES
    )
    filter_measures=models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        verbose_name='Единица измерения',
        help_text='Единица измерения для фильтра'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Категория - "{self.category.name}" | Характеристика -"{self.feature_name}"'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# admin.py

class ProductFeaturesInline(admin.TabularInline)
    model = ProductFeatures


class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ProductFeaturesInline]
```

Comment: спасибо работает, только при добавлении характеристик в продукте получаю ошибку  value must be valid JSON.

Comment: @Kirill а раньше работало? так то у вас указано `characteristics = JSONField(blank=True,null=True)`

Comment: Вот мне туда и нужно как то мои характеристики прикрепить

Comment: @Kirill Конкретно в это поле вроде как не получится. Можно сделать по аналогии с категорией. В `ProductFeatures ` добавить поле `product` и связь `ForeignKey ` на вашу модель `Product `. Тогда при создании продукта в админке к нему можно будет прикреплять `ProductFeatures `

Comment: Тогда по большому счету мне поле характеристик в продукте не нужны? как тогда вывести характеристики для каждой категории из ProductFeatures? и вставлять фильтры на странице категорий, спасибо!

Comment: есть функция     def get_characteristics. как я через нее могу получить характеристики